# How to add a try & except construct so that the script ignores that there is no file

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys, construct

I don't really know the Python language, so I'm asking for help from experts. I have a simple script and I need to add a construct to it

```
try:
except:
```

this is necessary so that the script ignores that there is no `'file.txt'` file and does not display an error.

If the file `"file.txt"` is missing, the script.py script displays the following **error**:

```
Version 1.2.1.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 10, in <module>
    with open("file.txt") as myfile, open("save.txt", 'a') as save_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file.txt'
```

How can I make the script ignore that there is no `'file.txt'` and not throw this errorTraceback (most recent call last) ?

**Script code:**

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if '-v' in sys.argv:
        print(f'Version 1.2.1.')


h = format(0x101101, 'x')[2:]

with open("file.txt") as myfile, open("save.txt", 'a') as save_file:

    for line in myfile:
        if h in line:
            save_file.write("Number = " + line + "")
            print("Number = " + line + "")
```

Help how to add a `try` & `except` construct to it?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Instead of assuming `file.txt` exists, why not pass the name of the file you want to read from as a command-line argument? (It seems like there is no point running the script *at all* if `file.txt` doesn't exist, so why not ensure that a file to read *does* exist when you run it?)

Answer (score 1):

Put `try:` and `except:` around the code, and use `pass` in the `except:` block to ignore the error

```
try:
    with open("file.txt") as myfile, open("save.txt", 'a') as save_file:
        for line in myfile:
            if h in line:
                save_file.write("Number = " + line + "")
                print("Number = " + line + "")
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You do the `try:` and then have the indented-block of code you want to try and if the error is raised, it'll go to that `except:` block of code and do whatever you want there.

```py
try:
    with open("file.txt") as myfile, open("save.txt", 'a') as save_file:
        for line in myfile:
            if h in line:
                save_file.write("Number = " + line + "")
                print("Number = " + line + "")
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("The error was found!")
    # or do whatever other code you want to do, maybe nothing (so pass)
    # maybe let the user know somehow, maybe do something else.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
   with open("file.txt") as myfile, open("save.txt", 'a') as save_file:

    for line in myfile:
        if h in line:
            save_file.write("Number = " + line + "")
            print("Number = " + line + "")
except NameError:
   print("file doesn't exist")
finally:
   print("regardless of the result of the try- and except blocks, this block will be executed")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).